# Ошибка Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

В первый раз использую `Generate Signed APK` , но вылезают такие ошибки: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.successdev.bookwindev.bookwin"
        vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = ['hdpi', 'xxhdpi']
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':caldroidcustom')
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файл `proguard-rules.pro` добавьте `-ignorewarnings`.